# Topology improvements?

Tags: topology

I am making a guitar, and I was wondering if there was any advice you have on making the topology for this?  I did a lot of things manually, like extruding and filling in faces on the front view.. but it takes awhile.  I started off with a circle, then starting extruding off of that, because there was a circly shape in it.  Is there a simple way to go about things, or does it just get time consuming mapping this all out?

Is there any mistakes, or have any advice on the given topology before I proceed? Or is it fine the way it is?

I'm fairly new to blender, and am just trying to learn things the correct way!  Thanks!

[image]

And after tinkering around a little bit I came up with this.

[image]

Here is a 3rd attempt at it a little differently.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your attempts are not bad at all. I really like the edgeflow in the second attempt. My only concern is the density of polygons in the middle of the model.

Personally I would do something like this:
[image]

When modelling, as a rule of thumb, always try to keep Your faces as square as possible and try to keep them all even sized.

This makes it easier to control the subsurface modifier, makes the model more flexible in animations, and makes it easier to prevent texture stretching.

I started with a face, went to edit mode, and edge select, extruded <kbd>E</kbd> the faces in top orthographic view. Then I rearranged the vertices, using <kbd>G</kbd> in the same view. 3-4 minutes of work in total.

But it really comes down to what you are going to use Your model for. High poly model, then I would try to tweak Your second attempt in order to even out the polygon size.

Comment: While I didn't cast the DV, maybe expand on ***why*** faces should be square and even sized.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to attempt to use the 2nd model and try to get things squared up.. I suppose just I ball them into more square shapes?  From what I understand, the more square they are they better they show up rendered?

Comment: This makes it easier to control the subsurface modifier, makes the model more flexible in animations, and makes it easier to prevent texture stretching. However I almost always stray from this path when I have to define the edges. As I like to bevel the edges in the modelling proces... There are a thousand ways to do this, and this is just what I tend to do